# Adaptive Regularization of Weights (AROW): classification dependent on feature index

Tags: machine-learning, feature-engineering

I am trying to classify texts using a bag of words algorithm. My feature vector is thus a large array of words. In order to build my feature vector, I parse the sample and put a one in the index corresponding to the word found. I use sparse format to represent the feature vectors. A little example to clarify:

```
feature vector = ('cat', 'dog', 'parrot', 'cow', 'fish')
sample = 'The cat is playing with the cow'
vector =  [0:1, 3:1]
```

I am using two classifiers in my tests: AROW and SVM. I found something very strange with the arow classifier: if I change the index of the words in my feature vector, classification results vary enormously. For example, if I change my initial feature vector to be:

```
feature vector = ('fish', 'parrot', 'cat', 'dog', 'cow')
```

My results won't be the same when I am using AROW. On the other hand, SVM gives exactly the same results. I am using the freely available AROW library http://code.google.com/p/arowpp/ in my tests. Is this a "feature" of AROW or is it likely an implementation bug in the open source library?

Comment: The AROW algorithm was proposed as one of solvers for the sequence tagging algorihtms. It may be that it inteprets the input as a sequence, not as a bag of words.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and yes, the problem is what @xeon mentions.

AROW often takes characters as features instead of words. The solution I found was to vectorize the words using `CountVectorizer` and use the feature IDs as the IDs from the vectorizer, which ensured it was using words not characters.